# Color Thief Not Changing Background

Tags: jquery, css, colors, color-thief

My first time working with Color Thief and I can't seem to get a background of a div to change its background color after checking the dominant color of an image. Here is the code I'm working with https://jsfiddle.net/una54dg6/

html:

```
<div class="blogPageHeader"></div>
<img src="https://i1.wp.com/metooplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Untitled-1.jpg?w=720" class="singlePostImg" />
```

jquery:

```
    $(".singlePostImg").load(function(){

    // Dominant Color
    var dominantColor = getDominantColor($(this));

    //change background
    $(".blogPageHeader").css("background-color", "rgb("+dominantColor+")");
});
```

Am I missing something? Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Try to run last line from browser's console with hard coded RGB value

Comment: I did that (added rgb(0,0,0) ) and nothing changed on the background, so I guess it isn't adding that css style to div. Not sure why that wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code block,

```
       var rgbColor = "rgb(" +dominantColor+ ")"; 
        console.log(rgbColor);
       $(".blogPageHeader").style.background = rgbColor;
```